# Pupeteer: take webpage screenshot with zoom (scale)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to take page screnshot of a particular width:

```
await page.setViewport({width: 320, height: 0})
await page.goto(url)
await page.screenshot({path: `screenshot.png`, fullPage: true});
```

The width of screenshot is exactly 320px. But is it possible to save scaled screenshot (e. g. 2 times larger)? Like in Developer Tools - I can set zoom 150% there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `deviceScaleFactor` on [`page.setViewport`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetviewportviewport)

```
await page.setViewport({width: 320, height: 0, deviceScaleFactor:2});
```

Comment: This is not the same as zoom. It does not trigger breakpoints etc. It also changes the number of pixels in the output image but shoudln't